# GRASS processing tools on Mac "ERROR: Sorry is not a valid option"

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, mac

using Qgis 2.18.15 on Osx I have some issue using the v.net.iso tool.

I launch the tool, but got no result at all. I can see the process goes by but no new layer at the end

Any idea?

[image]

Code in english:

```
Processing algorithm 1/1...
Algorithm v.net.iso - Splits network by cost isolines. starting...
g.proj -c proj4="+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1 input="/Users/arthur/Downloads" layer=Réseau routier output=tmp151629185596 --overwrite -o
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1 input="/Users/arthur/Downloads" layer=Depart output=tmp151629185597 --overwrite -o
g.region n=6519560.77083 s=6192397.02036 e=578658.942662 w=310247.58508 res=100
v.net -s input=tmp151629185596 points=tmp151629185597 out=tmp151629185598 op=connect threshold=50
v.db.connect -o map=tmp151629185598 table=tmp151629185597 layer=2
v.net.iso input="tmp151629185598" arc_type=line center_cats="1-100000" costs="1000,2000,3000" output=outpute72986cd648e4dbcbaf8e3bdae19134c --overwrite
v.out.ogr -s -e input=outpute72986cd648e4dbcbaf8e3bdae19134c type=auto output="/Users/arthur/Downloads" format=ESRI_Shapefile output_layer=TESTESTESTESTEST --overwrite
WARNING: Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale. 
Starting GRASS GIS... 
Executing '/Users/arthur/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' ... 
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default 
Projection information updated 

Description: 
Imports vector data into a GRASS vector map using OGR library. 

Keywords: 
vector, import, OGR 

Usage: 
v.in.ogr [-flc2tojrewi] input=string [layer=string[,string,...]] 
[output=name] [spatial=xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax[,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax,...]] 
[where=sql_query] [min_area=value] [type=string[,string,...]] 
[snap=value] [location=name] [columns=name[,name,...]] 
[encoding=string] [key=string] [geometry=name] [--overwrite] [--help] 
[--verbose] [--quiet] [--ui] 

Flags: 
-f List supported OGR formats and exit 
-l List available OGR layers in data source and exit 
-c Do not clean polygons (not recommended) 
-2 Force 2D output even if input is 3D 
Useful if input is 3D but all z coordinates are identical 
-t Do not create attribute table 
-o Override dataset projection (use location's projection) 
-j Perform projection check only and exit 
-r Limit import to the current region 
-e Extend region extents based on new dataset 
Also updates the default region if in the PERMANENT mapset 
-w Change column names to lowercase characters 
-i Create the location specified by the "location" parameter and exit. Do not import the vector data. 
--o Allow output files to overwrite existing files 
--h Print usage summary 
--v Verbose module output 
--q Quiet module output 
--ui Force launching GUI dialog 

Parameters: 
input OGR datasource name 
Examples: 
ESRI Shapefile: directory containing shapefiles 
MapInfo File: directory containing mapinfo files 
layer OGR layer name. If not given, all available layers are imported 
Examples: 
ESRI Shapefile: shapefile name 
MapInfo File: mapinfo file name 
output Name for output vector map 
spatial Import subregion only 
Format: xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax - usually W,S,E,N 
where WHERE conditions of SQL statement without 'where' keyword 
Example: income = 10000 
min_area Minimum size of area to be imported (square meters) 
Smaller areas and islands are ignored. Should be greater than snap^2 
default: 0.0001 
type Optionally change default input type 
options: point,line,boundary,centroid 
default: 
point: import area centroids as points 
line: import area boundaries as lines 
boundary: import lines as area boundaries 
centroid: import points as centroids 
snap Snapping threshold for boundaries (map units) 
'-1' for no snap 
default: -1 
location Name for new location to create 
columns List of column names to be used instead of original names, first is used for category column 
encoding Encoding value for attribute data 
Overrides encoding interpretation, useful when importing ESRI Shapefile 
key Name of column used for categories 
If not given, categories are generated as unique values and stored in 'cat' column 
geometry Name of geometry column 
If not given, all geometry columns from the input are used 

ERROR: Sorry is not a valid option 
ERROR 4: Unable to open /Users/arthur/Downloads/aquitaine-latest-free.shx or /Users/arthur/Downloads/aquitaine-latest-free.SHX.Try --config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX true to restore or create it 
ERROR 4: Failed to open file /Users/arthur/Downloads/aquitaine-latest-free.shp. 
It may be corrupt or read-only file accessed in update mode. 

WARNING: Datum not recognised by GRASS and no parameters found 
Over-riding projection check 
Check if OGR layer contains polygons... 
0..100 
Importing 1 features (OGR layer )... 
0..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Building topology for vector map ... 
Registering primitives... 

One primitive registered 
One vertex registered 
Building areas... 
0..100 
0 areas built 
0 isles built 
Attaching islands... 
Attaching centroids... 
100 
Number of nodes: 0 
Number of primitives: 1 
Number of points: 1 
Number of lines: 0 
Number of boundaries: 0 
Number of centroids: 0 
Number of areas: 0 
Number of isles: 0 
ERROR: Vector map not found 
ERROR: Vector map not found in current mapset 
ERROR: Vector map not found 
ERROR: Vector map not found 
Execution of '/Users/arthur/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' finished. 
Cleaning up temporary files... 
WARNING: Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale. 
Starting GRASS GIS... 
Executing '/Users/arthur/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' ... 
ERROR: Vector map not found 
Execution of '/Users/arthur/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' finished. 
Cleaning up temporary files... 
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm v.net.iso - Splits network by cost isolines. correctly executed...
```

Here is the paramaters used:
 [image]

Link to dataset: https://framadrop.org/r/jFGbIIfYXn#MfkJ/0YmRmhwCGxhzllsq+617drvUIoISPpU8rWWTww=

Comment: it would be more helpful if you switch to English interface

Comment: I edited my post with error log in english

Comment: Do other GRASS tools work? Can you provide test data? Please add a screenshot of the settings you used.

Comment: Question has been edited with dataset. Ragarding other grass tool, same problem

Comment: Any idea on what to do?